# How do I disable Java assertions for a junit test in the code

Tags: java, junit, assert

How do I disable java assertions (not junit assert) for a junit test in the code

Ive written a junit test but when I run it it doesnt fail as expected because assertions are enabled, whereas they are not in production.

Is there a way to disable assertions just in the code so that it work as expected when run within IDE and when built as part of Maven

Comment: I always feel sad when I see questions like this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typically you use surefire with maven for JUnit tests. Adding `-disableassertions` or the synonym `-da` as an argument should work:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>your_version</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-disableassertions</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If the tests are launched different through the IDE (that is outside of maven), you probably need to edit some launch configuration and pass the parameter. This is, however, IDE dependent.

Comment: I would disable them through class or package as described here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#enable-disable

Comment: the question was if I could modify assertion behaviour within code, not within parameters passed to java. But Im assuming that is impossible and therefore you give the correct solution.

Answer (score 14):

**Within Java (disabling assertions in *single* class)**

To enable or disable assertion checking within Java use [setClassAssertionStatus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#setClassAssertionStatus-java.lang.String-boolean-) in the ClassLoader. For example:

```
Foo.class.getClassLoader().setClassAssertionStatus(Foo.class.getName(), false);
```

**Within Maven (disabling assertions for *all* classes)**

Since version 2.3.1, Maven Surefire has a separate [enableAssertions](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#enableAssertions) flag.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>your_version</version>
  <configuration>
    <enableAssertions>false</enableAssertions>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**With JUnit 4 Assume (for single *test* case)**

Ideally, your tests should pass regardless of assertions are enabled or disabled. If one of the tests depends on assertions being disabled, the intended JUnit mechanism is to use an [*assumption*](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html):

```
import static org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue;

@Test
public foo onlyWithoutAssertions() {
    assumeTrue(assertionsDisabled());
    // your tricky test comes here, and is only executed in 
    // environments with assertion checking disabled.
}

public static boolean assertionsDisabled() {
    return !Foo.class.desiredAssertionStatus();
}
```

Note: I typically use this option the other way around: To check that an `assert` works as expected, in rare cases I have a test that assumes that assertion checking is *enabled*.

**With JUnit 5 Assume**

[JUnit 5 assumptions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assumptions) are an extension of the JUnit 4 ones.
Thus, for JUnit 5, the only change to the JUnit 4 code is the import, which now is from jupiter:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions.assumeTrue;
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at `-da` and `-ea` [parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) for `java` tool. So, in you case just use one of them (+ specify correspond package on your application) as you want to disable or enable assertions.

> With no arguments, `-enableassertions` or `-ea` enables assertions.
>
> - With one argument ending in "`...`", the switch enables assertions in the **specified package and any subpackages**.
> - If the argument is "`...`", then the switch enables assertions in the **unnamed package in the current working directory**.
> - With one argument not ending in "`...`", the switch enables assertions in the **specified class**.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Do you use such (java) assertion at all, if you disable assertions during tests? If no, just remove given assertion! It is just boilerplate.

If you use it (in some UI tests, acceptance tests or in performance tests) and thus you are expecting that given asserts will catch some regressions and they will be not triggered during normal release pipeline, it is good thing to check if someone has not removed such assertion without any knowledge!

You can expect exception (AssertionError extends Error extends Throwable) in test. Use `assertThrows` in junit testing for example.