# Debugging with the assert statement

Tags: java, assert

I'm assuming that the reason the `assert` statement throws an `AssertionError` to stop your program is because an assumption about your code is wrong. The problem is, how am I supposed to debug my code by using debugging tools when the assert statement kills my java process?

EDIT: My question is different because the answer to the supposedly duplicate question doesn't answer mine.

Comment: Most IDEs allow you to break when an exception is thrown..

Comment: You put break point before assert.

Comment: @Blorgbeard But in that case you could break on any exception. Why use assert - why not just throw any old exception?

Comment: @tsolakp That's not reliable because I'll only know where to put the breakpoint in hindsight AFTER the assertionerror has been thrown and my VM has suspended. In which case I will have to restart my program so I've lost all the config that caused that error.

Comment: Are you saying you don't know where the assertion error is coming from?

Comment: @tsolakp I'm saying I can only add the breakpoint before the assert statement once it's already happened.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable Java assertions for a junit test in the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901375/how-do-i-disable-java-assertions-for-a-junit-test-in-the-code)

Comment: @tkruse That's not a duplicate at all. It's got nothing to do with what I'm asking.

Comment: *Why use assert - why not just throw any old exception?* Assertions can be disabled, allowing you to avoid the performance hit in production.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 
If you look for a way to throw an exception and not throw an exception at the same time, there is no solution for this.

In modern IDEs you can, during debug:

1. tell the IDE to block on any AssertionError without setting any breakpoint
2. change the code of a method during a test when blocked, such as commenting out an assert
3. tell the IDE to resume running a method again [How to step back in Eclipse debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331336/how-to-step-back-in-eclipse-debugger)

Also assert can be disabled for the purpose of debugging. That's one reason to use an assert instead of an if-block.

See:
[How do I disable Java assertions for a junit test in the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901375/how-do-i-disable-java-assertions-for-a-junit-test-in-the-code)